# How to programmatically read button actions of another application (which is not installed) on Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am new to the windows application. I have a windows application which is directly running on double click operation without installation. Application's folder contains all dependencies for its operation.

I would like to find this windows application and access its buttons operation. I have tried to find its button control through Microsoft's spy++ tool but unable to find its control-id. Even Application name shown in Microsoft's spy++ tool is not acceptable by "FindWindowEx" function.